# How to rotate Scene Collection TileSet

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot-4

I am using a scene in a TileMap node, but I can't seem to be able to rotate it. I tried rotating it in code, but that doesn't work. I also tried rotating it in the editor using the TileMap node.

Is it possible at all to rotate a Scene TileMap? If so, how?

The Code I used to try and rotate:

```
func _ready():
    rotation_degrees = 90
```

I also tried using X and Z to rotate the Tile, but it says cannot transform tile scenes

[image]

Comment: It seems like I somehow fixed it. I will try to figure out how though.